# Jquery autocomplete have spaces between results and results not showing up in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So my page is a basic school student/class manager. Currently I  have two search bars which call different API calls which both return a List. The only problem is when I am displaying my results they have spaces between the results. Also another problem I am having is my autocomplete for my modal is hiding the results behind the popup.

```
BOB | Math

TIM | Science

Sarah | ENGLISH
```

Here is my HTML

```
<html>
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Search Name</div>
    <div class="card-body" style="min-height:90px;">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label text-right">Search</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6 autocomplete">
                <li class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible ui-menu-item"></li>
                <input id="nameSearch" class="col-md-6 form-control mdb-autocomplete input-sm" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body mx-0">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label textRightMiddle">Class Search</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 contRight autocomplete">
            <input id="classSearch" class="col-md-6 form-control mdb-autocomplete input-sm form-control validate" type="text" placeholder="Enter Class">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 contRight autocomplete">
            <li class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible ui-menu-item"></li>
            <input type="text" id="removeAutocomplete" class="btn btn-success form-control mdb-autocomplete input-sm" name="removeClassbutton" placeholder="Enter Class" onClick="removeClassfunction();">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

And here is my JS code

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#nameSearch").autocomplete({
        delay:100,
        source: function(request ,response){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: APICALL,
                datatype: 'json',
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    'name': $('#nameSearch')[0].value
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $("#classSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function(request ,response){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: APICALL,
                datatype: 'json',
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    'class': $('#removeAutocomplete')[0].value
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

I have tried adding `#nameSearch { position: absolute; }` and `#classSearch{ position: absolute;}` to my style but I have had no luck.

EDIT 1: I am stripping away unneeded that I discovered had no effect and lead me to the same problem.

Comment: Based on the code you have provided, there are a number of issues. 1. `messages` is not a part of jQuery UI Autocomplete. 2. When using a function for `source`, result data must be passed back to `response` function and I do not see that happening. 3. This post does not include any example of the data that is returned from the AJAX call. Please ensure you use a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Twisty I am slowly going over this code again to strip away that have no effect while still recreating this same problem

Answer (score 1):

What did you mean from "have spaces between the results"? Is it the space in each list item or space between ?

If you mean the space between each lish, you must take a look your server code not your frontend code. And if you mean the space between , just move your  near .

And your problem with "modal is hiding the results behind the popup" simply put css: z-index:99999 !important; in your css file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The content of your answer looks more like a comment than an answer. You may want to consider removing your answer and posting it as a comment. If you leave it as an answer it may get downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that this kind of problem wasn't an issue with the JS or HTML code. It came down to the CSS code that was put in place by someone else. Originally I had this

```
.ui-menu-item {
            top: 27% !important;
            background: #B1D3C5;
            z-index: 999;
            margin:24px 0 0 -40px !important;
            padding:5px; left: 8px !important;
            width: auto; list-style: none;
            border-radius:2px;
        }
```

And the `margin` was causing the extra space to be added after each result. I removed that and that fixed my issues.